# How can I unit test methods which are using static methods?

Tags: unit-testing, static-methods

Let's assume I wrote an extension method in [C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/info) for `byte` arrays which encodes them into hex strings, as follows:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToHex(this byte[] binary)
    {
        const string chars = "0123456789abcdef";
        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var b in binary)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(chars[(b >> 4) & 0xf]).Append(chars[b & 0xf]);
        }
        return resultBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I could test the method above using [NUnit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/nunit/info) as follows:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestToHex_Works()
{
    var bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
    Assert.AreEqual("0123456789abcdef", bytes.ToHex());
}
```

If I use the `Extensions.ToHex` inside my project, let's assume in `Foo.Do` method as follows:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public bool Do(byte[] payload)
    {
        var data = "ES=" + payload.ToHex() + "ff";
        // ...
        return data.Length > 5;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then all tests of `Foo.Do` will depend on the success of `TestToHex_Works`.

Using free functions in [C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info) the outcome will be the same: tests that test methods that use free functions will depend on the success of free function tests.

How can I handle such situations? Can I somehow resolve these test dependencies? Is there a better way to test the code snippets above?

Comment: `Then all tests of Foo.Do will depend on the success of TestToHex_works` -- So?  You don't have classes that depend on the success of other classes?

Comment: I've never quite understood this obsession with free/static functions and their so-called non-testability.  If a free function is free of side-effects, it is the easiest thing on the planet to test and prove it works. You've demonstrated this quite effectively in your own question.  How do you test ordinary, side-effect free methods (that aren't dependent on class state) in object instances?  I know you have some of those.

Comment: The only downside of this code using static functions is that you can’t easily use something else than `toHex` (or swap implementations). Apart from that everything is fine. Your code converting to hex is tested, now there’s another code using that tested code as a utility to achieve its own goal.

Comment: I am completely missing what is the problem here.  If ToHex doesn't work, then it's clear that Do won't work either.

Comment: The test for Foo.Do() shouldn't know or care that it calls ToHex() under the covers, that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Then all tests of `Foo.Do` will depend on the success of `TestToHex`_Works.

Yes. That's why you have tests for `TextToHex`. If those tests pass, the function meets the spec defined in those tests. So `Foo.Do` can safely call it and not worry about it. It's covered already.

You could add an interface, make the method an instance method and inject it into `Foo`. Then you could mock `TextToHex`. But now you have to write a mock, which may function differently. So you'll need an "integration" test to bring the two together to ensure the parts really work together. What has that achieved other than making things more complex?

The idea that unit tests should test parts of your code in isolation from other parts is a fallacy. The "unit" in a unit test is an isolated unit of execution. If two tests can be run simultaneously without affecting each other, then they run in isolation and so are unit tests. Static functions that are fast, do not have a complex set up and have no side effects such as your example are therefore fine to use directly in unit tests. If you have code that is slow, complex to set up or has side effects, then mocks are useful. They should be avoided elsewhere though.

Comment: You make a pretty good argument for "test-first" development.  Mocking exists in part because code gets written in such a way that it is too hard to test, and if you write your tests first, you force yourself to write code that is more easily testable.

Comment: I'm upvoting purely for recommending not mocking pure functions. Seen that too many times.

Answer (score 2):

> Using free functions in C++ the outcome will be the same: tests that
>   test methods that use free functions will depend on the success of
>   free function tests.
>
> How can I handle such situations? Can I somehow resolve these test
>   dependencies? Is there a better way to test the code snippets above?

Well, I don't see dependency here. At least not the kind that forces us to execute one test before another. The dependency we build among tests (no matter the kind) is one *confidence*.

We build a piece of code *(test-first or not)* and we ensure tests pass. Then, we are in a position of building more code. All the code built upon this first is built upon confidence and certainty. This is more or less what @DavidArno explains (very well) in his answer.

> *Yes. That's why you have tests for X. If those tests pass, the
>   function meets the spec defined in those tests. So Y can safely
>   call it and not worry about it. It's covered already.*

Unit tests should run in any order, any time, any environment and as fast as possible. Whether `TestToHex_Works` is executed the first or the last should not worry you.

If `TestToHex_Works` fails due to errors in `ToHex`, all tests relying on `ToHex` will end with different results and fail (ideally). The key here is detecting those different results. We do it making unit tests to be deterministic. As you do here

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
Assert.AreEqual("0123456789abcdef", bytes.ToHex());
```

Further unit tests relying on `ToHex` should also be deterministic. If everything in `ToHex` goes well, the result should be the expected one. If you get a different one, something went wrong, somewhere and this is what you want from a unit test, to detect these subtle changes and fail fast.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky with such a minimal example, but let's reconsider what we're doing:

> Let's assume I wrote an extension method in c# for byte arrays which encodes them into hex strings, as follows:

Why did you write an extension method to do this? Unless you're writing a library to encode byte arrays into strings, this isn't likely to be the requirement you're trying to fulfill. What it looks like you were doing here was trying to fulfill the requirement "Validate some payload which is a byte array" - so the unit tests you're implementing should be "Given a valid payload X, my method returns true" and "Given an invalid payload Y, my method returns false".

So when you initially implement this, you might do the "byte-to-hex" stuff inline in the method. And that's fine. Then later you get some other requirement (e.g. "Display the payload as a hex string") which, while you're implementing it, you realise also requires you to convert a byte array to a hex string. At that point you create your extension method, refactor the old method, and call it from your new code. Your tests for the validation functionality shouldn't change. Your tests for displaying the payload should be the same whether the bytes-to-hex code was inline or in a static method. *The static method is an implementation detail you shouldn't care about when writing the tests.* The code in the static method will be tested by its consumers. I wouldn't even bother writing tests for it.

Comment: "this isn't likely to be the requirement you're trying to fulfill. What it looks like you were doing here was trying to fulfill the requirement " - you're making a lot of assumptions about the purpose of a function that most likely was just picked as a representative example, and not something out of a larger program.

Comment: The "unit" in "unit testing" doesn't mean a single function, or class. It means a unit of functionality. Unless you're specifically writing a library that converted bytes to strings, that part is very much an implementation detail of some more useful bit of behaviour. That useful behaviour is the part you want to have tests for, because that's the bit you care about being correct. In an ideal world you want to be able to find a library already exists for doing the bin-to-hex (or whatever it is, don't get hung up on the specifics), swap it out for your implementation and not change any tests.

Comment: The devil is in the details. Unit testing "implementation details" is still an enormously useful thing to do and is not something to skim over.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. And this is one of the problems with static methods, another one being that OOP is a much better alternative in most situations.

This is also one of the reasons Dependency Injection is used.

In your case, you may prefer having a **concrete converter** that you inject into a class which needs a conversion of some values to hexadecimal. An **interface**, implemented by this concrete class, would define the contract required to convert the values.

Not only would you be able to test your code easier, but you'll also be able to swap implementations later (since there are lots of other possible ways of converting values to hexadecimal, some of them producing different outputs).

Comment: How will that not make the code dependant on the success of the converter tests ? Injecting a class, an interface or anything you want does not make it magically work. If you were talking about side effects then yes there would be a ton of value injecting a fake instead of hard coding an implementation, but that problem never existed in the first place anyway.

Comment: @steve when a unit fails do you want to see a sea of red in your test results, or just have the broken code show red?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: in a context of the unit tests, you're not injecting the real class, but a stub or a mock, which would not do the actual conversion, but just return hard-coded values to a specific set of inputs.

Comment: @Ewan If you see a sea of red when breaking the `toHex` static function, then the real problem lies in the design of the code; using a hard-coded static function everywhere. Also, in this case, seeing tons of tests breaking isn't really a big deal as fixing one test will fix every other test. And since this is all in memory and there's no side effect, running all the tests should take less than 10ms at most.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko so when injecting a calculator class implementing a `multiply` method, you'd mock this? Which means in order to refactor (and use the * operator instead), you'll have to change every single mock declaration in your code? Doesn't look like easy code to me. All I'm saying is `toHex` is very simple and has no side effects at all so I don't see any reason to mock or stub this. It's too much cost for absolutely no profit. Not saying we shouldn't inject it though, but that depends on usage.

Comment: @steve surely this is exactly what arseni is saying. The static call is bad design, you want your _unit_ tests to test specific parts of the code and static prevents this. Saying 'its a simple function that will never break' doesnt help you when it does break

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: I wouldn't call it “very simple,” nor would it remain unchanged forever, including when it comes to its output (should the string be prefixed with “0x”? Why aren't A-F characters in uppercase?) .NET Framework, for instance, has a method to do such conversion, but the output would be very different. There are design errors as well, such as the use of an array, which is extremely restrictive (and possibly false). There is also a bug which would cause a `NullReferenceException`. The binary logic is way too complex for the easy task.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: This means that this “very simple” method could and possibly would be refactored or simply changed. Every change would cause a risk of breaking a lot of tests. If the method is used all over the code, it could virtually cause hundreds of tests to be broken. You don't want to find yourself at 7 p.m. on Friday in front of a broken build with hundreds of tests passing red, wondering which one is the right one.

Comment: @17of26: why would I waste my time debugging on Friday evening, when I can just follow a *single failed test*, fix the build right now, and go home?

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko So that super complex method got changed, but the one changing that code didn't run the tests at all during those changes? You still didn't answer about my example on a calculator class being injected. Are you ever *not* mocking anything? The main reason I hate mocking is that I simply don't have the time to modify every single mocking declaration in every test when I only want to change a small part of the app I'm working on. They're useful sometimes, but tests feel way easier to understand/write/modify without them though.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: as for the complexity of having an interface, first, come on, the five liner with some binary logic and bugs in it that, I suppose, you haven't even noticed is “very simple,” and having an interface with one method inside “doesn't look like easy code”? Seriously? Second, this is the price to pay for (1) a better design and (2) more flexibility in the future (and, as already explained, (3) real unit tests which pinpoint the location of an issue).

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: While I'm a strong proponent of KISS and YAGNI, I'm not particularly fond of propagating a specific implementation all over the code base. Worked too much on legacy code where programmers did exactly that; it's not a particularly enjoyable experience.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: regarding your last comment, the implementation of a calculator class depends on a lot of details. I'm not sure why there is a `multiply` method in the first place. As for your question whether there cases where stuff is not mocked, obviously they are: basic framework methods (such as `Math.Min` in a context of a business application), and things which are directly related to the class using them (following Single responsibility principle).

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko I wasn't clear, I don't think having an interface is complex at all in this situation. I was saying that using mocks in these situations seem overkill and make tests harder to read, to write and to modify. When I say "doesn't look like easy code", I'm extrapolating to the case where `toHex` is used everywhere and so if tested with mocking every time well for any change I'll have to change many tests, right?

Comment: @Ewan, if I modified a piece of code and then faced "*a sea of red*", I *could* think oh no, where do I start?. But maybe I could just go back to the piece of code I just modified and look at its tests first to see what I broke. :p

Comment: @steve the OP is basically "how do i mock statics" though. Sure you dont like mocking. But....

Comment: @davidarno lets hope you dont work with any rockstars who dont believe in testing their checkins

Comment: @Ewan, [we can all be Rockstar developers these days](https://github.com/RockstarLang/rockstar).

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko, if DI makes your design so much better, why don't I see arguments for injecting types like `String` and `int` as well? Or basic utility classes from the standard library?

Comment: Your answer completely ignores practical aspects. There are **plenty** of situations with static methods that are fast, self-contained, and unlikely enough to ever change, that going to the effort of injecting them or jumping through any hoop other than a regular function call, is a pointless waste of time and effort.

Comment: I completely agree with @ArseniMourzenko. For me the main reason I'd want to mock extensions like this (hence I would not make it an extension in a first place) is because I do not want to write similar tests for consumers to verify the same logic over and over. I.e. I want to be able to mock it and not care about what it returns in which format. I trust that implementation of `ToHex()` is covered with unit tests, and rely that it behaves as expected. Otherwise single change in extension method may invalidate multiple consumer tests.

Comment: Furthermore, I believe that C# language tries to be as friendly as possible to developers in pursuit to be as minimal as, for example, JS/TS (with Node.js). A good example would be minimal API that looks similar to express.js. But the reason why JS/TS can get away with oversimplification is because in JS anything can be mocked, where is in C# it's not as easy.